# Updating test case in rally by ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber, rally

I am trying to update test case of a particular scenario. But it saying that undefined method update for :test_case symbol.

Need help on this..

My updating method is....

```
def dataValidInput(featName,testCase)
  fields = {:workspace => @rally["workspace"],
    :project => @rally["project"],
    :work_product => featName,
    :test_case => testCase,
    :validation_input => @step_name,
    :name => testCase}
  test_case = @slm.update(:test_case,fields)
end
```

Am getting output as...

```
undefined method `update' for :test_case:Symbol (NoMethodError)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rally_rest_api-1.1.0/lib  /rally_rest_api/rally_rest.rb:105:in `update'
C:/Users/CukesRally/features/CreateTC10.rb:176:in `nilValidInput'
C:/Users/CukesRally/features/CreateTC10.rb:154:in `chek_Steps'
C:/Users/CukesRally/features/CreateTC10.rb:132:in `find_or_create_test_case'
C:/Users/CukesRally/features/CreateTC10.rb:104:in `after_features'
C:/Users/CukesRally/features/CreateTC10.rb:93:in `before_test_case'
```

My Command :

```
cucumber C:/Users/CukesRally/features/Plan.feature --format MyTest::CreateStep
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I see that you're using an outdated gem. Please switch to using the rally_api gem. The latest version is 1.1.2: https://rubygems.org/gems/rally_api/versions/1.1.2

Then, if you still need help, please point me to a repo where the code is located or provide a gist link. I'd like to know where @slm and :work_product are defined as they seem to be the source of your error.

Comment: I am using rally_api 1.1.2 gem only. In above output it showing rally_rest_api version 1.1.0.. Am instanting RallyRestApi and using @slm as variable (@slm= RallyRestApi.new(:url, :username, :password) –

Comment: The two gems are very similarly named and I think you're using the old/outdated one. To verify this, go into command line for your project and type 'gem list' to see the list of gems and copy-paste it here. I believe you are running the old rally_rest_api gem (see https://rubygems.org/gems/rally_rest_api) instead of the new rally_api gem (see https://rubygems.org/gems/rally_api/versions/1.1.2). In the new gem, the class name you instantiate is different (example:     @rally = RallyAPI::RallyRestJson.new(config))

Comment: *** LOCAL GEMS ***

activemodel (4.2.1)
activeresource (4.0.0, 2.3.4)
activesupport (4.2.1, 2.3.4)
bigdecimal (1.2.6)
builder (3.2.2)
cucumber (2.0.0)
cucumber-core (1.1.3)
cucumber-to-rally (0.1.3)
debase (0.1.2)
debase-ruby_core_source (0.7.8)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
domain_name (0.5.23)
formatter (0.1.0)
formatter-date (0.1.1)
formatter-number (0.1.0)
gherkin (2.12.2)
http-cookie (1.0.2)
httpclient (2.6.0.1, 2.4.0)
i18n (0.7.0)
io-console (0.4.3)
java-properties (0.0.2)
java_properties (0.0.4)
json (1.8.1)
logeasy (0.0.8)
logger (1.2.8)
mime-types (2.4.3)

Comment: mini_portile (0.6.2)
minitest (5.4.3)
multi_json (1.11.0)
multi_test (0.1.2)
net-http-digest_auth (1.4)
net-http-persistent (2.9.4)
ntlm-http (0.1.1)
optparse-command (0.1.8)
power_assert (0.2.2)
properties-ruby (0.0.4)
psych (2.0.8)
rails-observers (0.1.2)
rake (10.4.2)
rally_api (1.1.2)
rally_rest_api (1.1.0)
rdoc (4.2.0)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.28)
test-unit (3.0.8)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
unf (0.1.4)
unf_ext (0.0.6)
webrobots (0.1.1)
yaml-lint (0.0.4)

Comment: Those are the gems I installed... When using RallyAPI::RallyRestJson.new(config), am unable to find workspace..

Comment: Piece of code 
slm = RallyAPI::RallyRestJson.new(conf)
      rally = Hash.new
      rally["slm"] = slm
      rally["workspace"] = slm.user.subscription.workspaces.find { |w| w.name == "workspace_name" }

Comment: First, you need to uninstall "rally_rest_api" as that is the old library and is what your errors were generated by.

Comment: If RallyAPI cannot find the workspace, then please verify the user in your config or connection has access to that workspace through the website. If it does, then your connection credentials are probably not configured correctly. Please refer to the readme for the rally_api gem at https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForRuby

Comment: Can't we update a test case by rally_rest_api? Our team developed a project under rally_rest_api. We just need a feature to update test case. We already creating user stories and test cases by finding workspace under rally_rest_api. When we are able to do user story creation, can't we update test case by rally_rest_api??